# Call to a member function fire_query() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysql, database, class, global

I keep getting the error Call to a member function fire_query() on a non-object, it's really frustrating, I just don't know what is wrong.

my class:

```
require_once("MySQLDatabase.class.php");  

global $database;
$result = $database->fire_query($query);
$object_array = array();
```

This is my MySQLDatabase class

```
<?php   
    require_once("config.php");
    class MySQLDatabase_class
    {
        //Some stuff


        public function fire_query($query)
        {
            $result = mysqli_query($this->db_connection, $query) or die("<font color='red'>Error code: 1x1003</font><br>".$query);
            return $result;
        }


        //Some more stuff
    }

    $database = new MySQLDatabase_class();
?>
```

I have done this tons of times, and it always works.
I just can't figure it out why "global $database" doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create new object here:

```
require_once("MySQLDatabase.class.php");  
$database = new MySQLDatabase_class();
global $database;
$result = $database->fire_query($query);
$object_array = array();
```

Comment: The is the point I already created a new object in the MySQLDatabase_class (at the bottom). By using global in my other class, I should be able to acces that variable